# Mysql: How do I fill in null values in one row with values from another row in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an id column that references a row from the same table that represents a set of default values the row should return if any of the values are NULL.  For example:

```
'content'
id | a   | b   | default_id
----------------------------------
1  | 33  | 55  | NULL
2  | NULL| 11  | 1
```

So I want to query row 2 in a way that I get back a result with 'a' = 33 and 'b' = 11.  Is there some simple way to do this?

Comment: what is the relation between row 1 and 2?

Comment: Is this for a limited number of columns, or are you looking for a generic solution to n-columns?

Comment: Ronnis:  Row 2 has a 'default_id' of 1, so I want empty columns in row 2 to be filled in with values from row 1.

Comment: Each row will have a different 'default_id' and there could be many records returned, each of which needs to be filled with its respective default values.

Comment: Brett:  A generic solution to n-columns, yes.  Though I am generating the query programmatically, so if I had to concat some column names together that is fine as long as it works for all of them, and I can do them all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function, whick returns the first non-NULL value in the list:

```
SELECT      COALESCE(c1.a, c2.a) a ,
            COALESCE(c1.b, c2.b) b
FROM        content c1
LEFT JOIN   content c2 ON (c2.id = c1.default_id)
WHERE       c1.id = 2;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE content (id int, a int, b int, default_id int);
INSERT INTO content VALUES (1, 33, 55, NULL);
INSERT INTO content VALUES (2, NULL, 11, 1);
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|   33 |   11 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: join condition should probably be `c2.id = c1.default_id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.id
      ,coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) as a
      ,coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b
  from content t1 
  left outer 
  join content t2 on(t1.default_id = t2.id)
 where t1.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT t1.id, IFNULL(t1.a, t2.a), IFNULL(t1.b,t2.b)

 FROM content t1

LEFT JOIN content t2 ON (t2.id = t1.default_id)

WHERE t1.id = 2`